# Methods and observations that help you achieve complete decomposition of a compound in decomposition analysis

Tags: stoichiometry, decomposition

Different chemicals decompose in different ways to give different observations, but they usually involve heating the compound to high temperatures.

My question is that what are your lab techniques that help you ensure the compound you're analyzing is fully decomposed? what do you usually look for that signifies that your compound has decomposed fully?

Comment: Typically you insure complete reaction via the reaction conditions.

Comment: Bomb calorimetry falls into this category: To determine the enthalpy of formation of a compound, you combust a known mass of a sample into water and carbon dioxide and then apply Hess's law of heat summation.  To do this successfully, the sample is enclosed in an atmosphere of pressurized pure oxygen gas (hence calling the device *bomb* calorimeter).

Comment: Your opening sentence is not quite clear, or the question for that matter. Do you have a specific technique in mind?